# How to bind model to the Spatie role?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

Is it possibe to attach specific model to the role in [Spatie laravel permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction)?

I need to get model depends role. For example if user has role doctor I need to get Doctor model. The same for clinic role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little hard to know what you are hunting for without knowing how you've set up the architecture underneath this, but you can get to the Doctors... not sure about binding directly though.

I assume you have created a Spatie role and assigned it to a Doctor class (which I assume is an extended User or similar, *and is using HasRoles*):

```
$role = Role::create(['name' => 'doctor']);
```

Grab a doctor and assign the role as normal:

```
$doctor = Doctor::find(xxx);
$doctor->assignRole($role);
```

I think the below may help:

```
$role= Role::findByName('doctor');
$roleClass= $role->getModel();
```

For the Docs with role doctor

```
$docs= Doctor::role('doctor')->get();
```

If you are looking to distinguish between class (Doctor, User), you'll need to run an extra command on a`$doc` (or even a superset like `User::role` collection) like `get_class` but this will depend on how you've set the query and flow up.  I'm not sure there is a direct method in Spatie to do exactly how you wish, but if you are OK with pulling a superset collection of users which might include the Doctor class, you can do it in two steps at least.

Comment: I did not get this $docs= Doctor::role('doctor')->get();. What is it?

Comment: That is a query to supply you with every User (or Doctor if you created this class) that has the role *doctor*.  If you use a base class of User, and then loop through this collection using `get_class`, this is one way to find Doctor class objects depending on how you run the builder... possibly.  Or have a hard separation with the class and assign the Role.  I can't find a direct way to do this in SPatie, but I think this is b/c they prolly assume folks would use a flag on the User object instead of a full class (or just the role).  But that doesn't mean it can't be done as above or similar.

Comment: So, I need to get model for auth user

Comment: I tried ```     $user = Auth::user()->getRoleNames();
        dd($user);``` but it is empty

Comment: Hmm, that method returns a *collection* of the **Roles** that are attached to a user.  I'd name the var like this to avoid confusion: `$roles = $user->getRoleNames();`.  If you have not assigned any roles to this user (previously using `assignRole()`), the `$roles` collection will be empty.

Comment: Problem is user model has not relations with doctor model. But in database doctor table has fk to the user as (user_id). So when I attach the role to the doctor model it uses the Doctor.id. instead Doctor.user_id. That is why I dont get roles from Auth()->user()->getRolesNamer(). Could you helpe me with that?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to reconsider your architecture a bit.  If the Doctor is an authenticated user, and has roles applied as a user of your app, then perhaps it should be a User object or extended object.  If the doctor is not an authenticated user (it is just a person info in the database), then using a Role may not be the best way to set this up - use a flag on the Doctor object instead.  Or if Doctor is an independent type of User, then add the `HasRoles` trait to the Doctor object, but this seems like a lot of overhead instead of using User and adding a flag to that class.

Comment: So, how to be?  I can define relations in user model like doctor, patient, clinic to bind with corresponding models. But I attempted to avoid this replacing on the roles. Exactly I have user model by default for authificated user. And I tried to find roles for this user and return a model depends role

Comment: Hard for me to say without knowing the whole purpose of your code.  But I would suggest (just from what I understand of how you are doing this): If the doctor, patient, and clinic **must log in**, then make them an authenticatable user with roles.  If they are just data points (and don't need to log in), just make them a data structure, not attached to a user, not attached to a role.  That data point might be `type` and could be 'doctor', 'patient' etc.  It would be like having a table with User and say... Employee.  The employee might have a `type` field for 'doctor' or whatever.